# Does anyone know any way of implementing an atomic action in C#?

Tags: c#

Atomic: Atomic means that all the statements (SQL statement or operations) that are a part of the transaction should work as atomic operation i.e. either all are successful or all should fail. 
i want to know if there is any way of implementing atomic actions in C#?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use the `TransactionScope` class for this purpose, which

> Makes a code block transactional

For implementation details, please have a look [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.transactions.transactionscope%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).